# Determining operator by inner product

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

It's been a while since I did any functional analysis. I am looking for a result that states the following.

Suppose we are given an inner product space $H$ and two linear operators, $A$ and $B$. Then $A = B$ iff for all $x$, $\langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle x, Bx \rangle$. In particular, I am concerned about the case where $H$ is a Hilbert space, namely $\ell^2$. A reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the following theorem:

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert-space, and $A, B \in B(H)$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

- $A = B$
- $\langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle x, Bx \rangle$ for all $x \in H$.

The complex part is really important because it does not hold in real Hilbert spaces. The proof of the theorem relies on the following complex polarization formula:
$$\langle y, Ax \rangle = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^4 i^k \bigg(\big\langle x+i^ky, A(x+i^ky)\big\rangle \bigg)$$

Here, I used the "physicist convention", i.e. the inner product is linear in its second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Any skew-Hermitian operator $A$ satisfies $\langle x,Ax\rangle=0 \ \forall x$ so this statement is false.

Comment: Are there any assumptions we can put on $A, B$ so that this would be true?

Comment: I believe that if the operator is bounded and Hermitian then it should work but there is a bit of subtlety because you are only comparing the operators in a weak sense. It has also been some time since I have done functional analysis so maybe someone else would be able to provide a result